# Как передать в метод изображение?

Tags: c#

Рисую аквариум на Bitmap. Есть функция, принимающая параметр типа Bitmap и возвращающая цвет текущего пикселя(координаты объекта в аквариуме):

```
private Color Look(Bitmap bp)
        {
            if (y - 1 < 0 || y + 1 > bp.Height || x - 1 < 0 || x + 1 > bp.Width)
                return Color.Aquamarine;
            return bp.GetPixel(x, y);
        }
```

Но в метод передаётся чёрное изображение. Проверил так: создал переменную и присвоил ей значение метода Look, отладчик показал значение 00000000. А что надо сделать, чтобы метод работал с отрисованным изображением(метод находится в отдельном классе)? Пробовал передавать объект Image, но безрезультатно.

Comment: не нужно дублировать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз. Достаточно добавить информацию в исходный вопрос.

Comment: И толку писать в тот вопрос, если он давно уже был и там никто не отвечает

Comment: при редактировании вопроса, он опять появляется на главной странице. Если не ответили на вопрос, из-за недостатка информации - то и при дублировании его этой же информации будет не хватать, следовательно на вопрос опять не ответят. Поэтому нужно отредактировать исходный вопрос, добавив в него всю необходимую информацию.